# C# WMI User Access Level detection

Tags: c#, wmi, system.management

I have a WMI query that do event trace for process start-up detection.
The code is similar to this:

```
var startProcessQuery = new WqlEventQuery("Win32_ProcessStartTrace", $"ProcessName = 'notepad.exe'");
var _startProcessEventWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(startProcessQuery);

_startProcessEventWatcher.EventArrived += StartProcessEventWatcher_EventArrived;
_startProcessEventWatcher.Start();
```

If the application is started with "normal" privileges (and not as administrator) when I try to start the event watcher I catch an System.Managenet.ManagementException with "Access denied" message.

I know that to monitor WMI events is better to be in administrator mode or is necessary to enable access also for "common" user but...

---

Is there a way (with c#) to detect the user access in WMI **before** doing the query or starting a watcher?

If yes, how is possible to query WMI for the current user access level against a specific scope (eg. trace events?)

Thank you
Lorenzo